# How do I block range of incoming IPs in Windows Advanced Firewall

Tags: windows, networking, dns, firewall

On Windows Server 2022 I am trying to block an IP range from

168.228.0.0 to 168.228.0.255

So having researched I came up with this:
168.228.0.0/16

However I am still getting DNS queries from random IP's that go like this despite my rule:

168.228.0.70
168.228.0.170
168.228.1.7
168.228.2.35

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The destination are public IPs (I see that you are connected in RDP to the Windows Server 2022). Could you please add the firewall rule you created to block ? - What is the Windows Server IP ?

Comment: rule is:

incoming
Block Connection
All programs 
Any protocol
All Local and Remote Ports

Scope:

168.228.0.0./16

Comment: You have a `.` before `/16` - Is it in the rule ? Or is it just a mistake ?

Comment: it is 168.228.0.0/16